# How to implement the versioning in the drools 6.0?

Tags: drools

How to implement the versioning in the drools 6.0?
We want to have own version maintenance for drools 6.0. WE want to maintain multiple version of drl files. We want to execute older version drl file,with existance of new versioned drl file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drools 6.x Workbench uses Git for version control of DRL and other artifacts. The Git documentation is here:

http://git-scm.com/documentation

If you're not using the Drools Workbench, then you can implement version control any way you feel like, as you will be building the knowledge base through the API. And Git would be a good way to do it.